# Installing ROracle (and the Oracle Instant Client?) on MacOS

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I'm trying to install ROracle. Since ROracle requires the Oracle OCI libraries, I downloaded these files from the Oracle website: instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.2.0.1.0, instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip. I put those files in ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew and install them using homebrew.

```
brew install instantclient-basic
brew install instantclient-sdk
```

The Oracle website also mentioned the need to set some environment variables, so I put this in my .bashrc file:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-basiclite/12.2.0.1.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-basiclite/12.2.0.1.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export NLS_LANG=UTF8
```

But trying to install ROracle in R leads to this:

```
> install.packages("ROracle")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 308252 bytes (301 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 301 KB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles'
* installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
** package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: error: OCI libraries not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ROracle’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status
```

R says it can't find the OCI libraries. Oracle's documentation has so far proven non-existent or worthless in resolving this issue, but I found a [comment on the internet that seemed promising](https://github.com/InstantClientTap/homebrew-instantclient/issues/11). So I wrote this into my .bashrc and ran it:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-basic/12.2.0.1.0/lib --with-oci-inc=/usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-sdk/12.2.0.1.0/lib/sdk/include' ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz
```

With this result:

```
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
****unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-
library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
    dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so, 6): Symbol 
    not found: _ons_recvthread_clone_sb
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-basic/12.2.0.1.0/lib/libons.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/instantclient-basic/12.2.0.1.0/lib/libons.dylib
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle’
```

So there's something wrong with libons.dylib? What am I supposed to do with that information?

Comment: I usually follow the [installation instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL) that come with the package, which means I tend to put the basic and sdk packages into the same directory, I symlink `libclntsh.dylib.12.1` and compile with just the oci-lib option.

Comment: I tried reinstalling everything again but now I'm getting an error, much like last time but with the following message:

unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Did you symlink that file? It looks like the problem lies there. I've never (successfully) installed ROracle with the instant client libraries installed via homebrew, I always download them myself and unzip them somewhere manually myself. I may not be much help beyond that. But I really, **really** empathize. I've been through this many times before.

Comment: I did make a symlink like the instructions said, although I am using the instant client version 12.2 and not 12.1. I might try 12.1 to see if it works

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://community.oracle.com/thread/4092751 which is under investigation in the Oracle bug noted there.

Comment: After trying 12.1 the error has changed to: `ld: library not found for -lclntsh
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ROracle.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ROracle’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/ROracle’`

Comment: Don't forget that Apple's 'recent' SIP changes affected runtime linking.  You generally need to put Instant Client in ~/lib or /usr/local/lib, since DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is no longer used in subshells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instant Client 12.2 for macOS was patched.  Get it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html and unzip it, for example into `~/instantclient_12_2`

I was able to install ROracle on macOS with:

```
brew install R
```

Update rpath in the library (using the correct version number for R):

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath ~/instantclient_12_2 /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

Run 'R' and then:

```
install.packages("DBI")
```

Download ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html and install it:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/Users/cjones/instantclient_12_2  --with-oci-inc=/Users/cjones/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include' ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz
```

Comment: I had shelved this project about a month ago, but I finally got ROracle working on my mac today using this guide. Thanks Christopher!

Comment: I tried your solution but I sitll get: 

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ROracle’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so, 6): Symbol not found: _OCIArrayDescriptorAlloc
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/ROracle/libs/ROracle.so
Errore: loading failed
Esecuzione interrotta
ERROR: loading failed

Answer (score 1):

A solution for that without `-add_rpath` can be found on [Intall ROracle Package for Windows and Mac OS](https://www.ecourse.org/news.asp?which=3233)

I use R from Macports and I did:

```
cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
sudo ln -s ~/Applications/instantclient/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
sudo ln -s ~/Applications/instantclient/libclntshcore.dylib.12.1
sudo ln -s libclntsh.dylib.12.1 libclntsh.dylib
sudo ln -s libclntshcore.dylib.12.1 libclntshcore.dylib
```

I think only the link to `libclntsh.dylib.12.1' is needed. But it does not harm to create the others as well. This way you do not need to run`install_name_tool` after every upgrade to R.

After creating the links I was able to install ROracle using `R CMD INSTALL`